# connecting python to the command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I'm watching a video on YouTube that that is telling me to type cd documents and then within that file type cd python to connect python, but every time I try this it says "the system cannot find the path specified" I don't understand why it is saying this because I can see that python is in my documents folder.

Comment: what is in the documents folder ? a file named `python` or a folder ?

Comment: there is no file named just python, there is  IDLE (python  3.8 32-bit), Python 3.8 (32-bit), Python 3.8 Manuals (32-bit), and Python 3.8 Module docs (32-bit).    these are in within a folder within documents, these files are directly in my documents

Comment: "I can see that python is in my documents folder." - if there is no folder or file is in your documents folder named python, why do you say that there is such ? "cd python" - how do you think you can cd to a directory that does not exist ? "I'm watching a video on YouTube" - If you talk about a video on YouTube, how about providing a link to it so that other people can watch it and tell you what you understood wrong / what is wrong in the video ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows CMD or Powershell, use the command `py` instead of `python`.

**Example:** `py myscript.py` (or `py.exe .\myscript.py` also works)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run the python code which is located in your documents folder then open cmd and type "cd documents" and if your python code is in same folder then type "python 'filename'.py" pre enter to run